# Left join with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace ids for their respective values. The problem is that each id has a different value according to the previous column `type`, like this:

```
>df
  type id 
1  q1   1
2  q1   2
3  q2   1
4  q2   3
5  q3   1
6  q3   2
```

Here's the type ids with its value:

```
>q1
  id value
1 1  yes
2 2  no

>q2 
   id value
1  1  one hour
2  2  two hours
3  3  more than two hours

>q3
  id value
1 1  blue
2 2  yellow
```

I've tried something like this:

```
df <- left_join(subset(df, type %in% c("q1"), q1, by = "id"))
```

But it removes the other values.

I' like to know how to do a `one liner solution` (or kind of) because there are more than 20 vectors with types description.

Any ideias on how to do it?

This is the df i'm expecting:

```
>df
  type id value
1  q1   1 yes
2  q1   2 no
3  q2   1 one hour
4  q2   3 more than two hours
5  q3   1 blue
6  q3   2 yellow
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join on more than one variable. The example df you give would actually make a suitable lookup table for this:

```
value_lookup <- data.frame(
  type = c('q1', 'q1', 'q2', 'q2', 'q3', 'q3'),
  id = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2),
  value = c('yes', 'no', 'one hour', 'more than two hours', 'blue', 'yellow')
)
```

Then you just merge on both `type` and `id`:

```
df <- left_join(df, value_lookup, by = c('type', 'id'))
```

Usually when I need a lookup table like that I store it in a CSV rather than write it all out in the code, but do whatever suits you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Is it possible to merge on both `type` OR  `id`?

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure what that would look like, in the example here that would lead to ambiguity. You should start a new question and give an example of what you would like to do and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
tempList = split(df, df$type)
do.call(rbind,
          lapply(names(tempList), function(nm)
              merge(tempList[[nm]], get(nm))))
#  id type               value
#1  1   q1                 yes
#2  2   q1                  no
#3  1   q2            one hour
#4  3   q2 more than two hours
#5  1   q3                blue
#6  2   q3              yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values of 'q\d+' data.frame object identifiers in a `list`, bind them together into a single data.frame with `bind_rows` while creating the 'type' column as the identifier name and `right_join` with the dataset object 'df'

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(paste0("q", 1:3)) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = 'type') %>% 
    right_join(df)
#  type id               value
#1   q1  1                 yes
#2   q1  2                  no
#3   q2  1            one hour
#4   q2  3 more than two hours
#5   q3  1                blue
#6   q3  2              yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a series of left joins:

```
df1 = left_join(df, q1, by='id') %>% filter(type=="q1")
> df1
  type id value
1   q1  1   yes
2   q1  2    no


df2 = left_join(df, q2, by='id') %>% filter(type=="q2")
> df2
  type id               value
1   q2  1            one hour
2   q2  3 more than two hours

df3 = left_join(df, q3, by='id') %>% filter(type=="q3")
> df3
  type id  value
1   q3  1   blue
2   q3  2 yellow

> rbind(df1,df2,df3)
  type id               value
1   q1  1                 yes
2   q1  2                  no
3   q2  1            one hour
4   q2  3 more than two hours
5   q3  1                blue
6   q3  2              yellow
```

One liner would be:

```
rbind(left_join(df, q1, by='id') %>% filter(type=="q1"),
        left_join(df, q2, by='id') %>% filter(type=="q2"),
            left_join(df, q3, by='id') %>% filter(type=="q3"))
```

If you have more vectors then probably you should loop through the names of vector types and execute left_join and bind_rows one by one as:

```
vecQs = c(paste("q", seq(1,3,1),sep="")) #Types of variables q1, q2 ...
result = tibble()

#Execute left_join for the types and store it in result.
for(i in vecQs) {       
     result = bind_rows(result, left_join(df,eval(as.symbol(i)) , by='id') %>% filter(type==!!i))
}
```

This will give:

```
> result
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  type     id value              
  <chr> <int> <chr>              
1 q1        1 yes                
2 q1        2 no                 
3 q2        1 one hour           
4 q2        3 more than two hours
5 q3        1 blue               
6 q3        2 yellow
```